# VSTS - Getting al Team Project Administrators using VSTS REST API

Tags: rest, api, tfs, azure-devops

Is it possible to get all project administrators per project? I found out I can get all projects and their team members using this API: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/teams#get-a-teams-members

But then I get a full list of members of the Team Project, and not their permissions. I want to have a list of administrators, so that I can contact them about their TeamProject.

Thanks in advance!

BTW, using TFS 2017

Answer (score 0):

There is no such REST API to get members from a VSTS group (such as Project Administrators) for now.

But there has an user voice [REST API for a better Projects and Team Management](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/16994026-rest-api-for-a-better-projects-and-team-management)  which contains similar function in the suggestions, you can vote and follow up.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be achieved via Rest API, but it can be achieved with SOAP API. Following is the code sample for your reference:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common;

namespace GetAdmin
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string projectname = "projectname";
            string groupname = $"[{projectname}]\\Project Administrators";
            TfsTeamProjectCollection ttpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("https://vstsaccount.visualstudio.com/"));
            IIdentityManagementService idms = ttpc.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();
            TeamFoundationIdentity admingroup = idms.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName,groupname,MembershipQuery.Direct,ReadIdentityOptions.IncludeReadFromSource);
            foreach (IdentityDescriptor tfi in admingroup.Members)
            {
                TeamFoundationIdentity member = idms.ReadIdentity(tfi,MembershipQuery.Expanded, ReadIdentityOptions.ExtendedProperties);
                Console.WriteLine(member.DisplayName);
                Console.WriteLine(member.GetProperty("Mail"));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Powershell Script:

```
$dllpath1 = "D:\\net45\\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll";
$dllpath2 = "D:\\net45\\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll";
$dllpath3 = "D:\\net45\\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.dll";
$dllpath4 = "D:\\net45\\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.Interactive.dll";

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($dllpath1);
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($dllpath2);
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($dllpath3);
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($dllpath4);

    $uri = "https://xxx.visualstudio.com/";
    $tfs = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($uri)
    $idservice = $tfs.GetService("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.FrameWork.Client.IIdentityManagementService")
    $projectname = "xxx"
    $groupname = "[" + $projectname + "]\Project Administrators";
    $admingroup = $idservice.ReadIdentity([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.FrameWork.Common.IdentitySearchFactor]::AccountName,$groupname,[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.FrameWork.Common.MembershipQuery]::Direct,[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.FrameWork.Common.ReadIdentityOptions]::IncludeReadFromSource)
    foreach ($id in $admingroup.Members)
    {
        $member = $idservice.ReadIdentity($id,[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.FrameWork.Common.MembershipQuery]::Expanded, [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.FrameWork.Common.ReadIdentityOptions]::ExtendedProperties)
        Write-Host $member.DisplayName
        Write-Host $member.GetProperty("Mail")
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! The sad thing is, I don't have access to the TFS server, so no possibility to include modules listed above. Also, I don't master C# (is it?) I need to be able to do this using powershell or python (from a commandline), because I'm going to schedule it using Cronacle (enterprise scheduler).

Comment: @EricJansen They are .Net Client Libraries we published for developer, you don't need the access to TFS Server. Just install it via nuget: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries

Comment: @EricJansen And I added powershell script for your reference. It uses the credential in team explorer, so you have to connect to the VSTS account in team explorer first and then run the script.